# Does PHP's SQLite3Stmt class cause locking problems?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm running PHP 5.3.3 (the latest in CentOS 6.5) as an Apache module with Prefork.

I found that an SQLite3 database will lock FOREVER until Apache is restarted, if the script runs out of time or memory in a certain way.

Reproducible test:

```
// Open a connection to the database.
$db = new SQLite3('/path/to/test.db');

// Get a reserved lock.
$db->exec('BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION');

// Construct a prepared statement SQLite3Stmt object.
$st = $db->prepare('SELECT value FROM sometable WHERE key=:key');

// Emulate the script running off the rails while calling the prepared statement.
while(true)
{
    $st->bindValue(':key', 1);
}
```

If you run this script, it runs out of execution time and/or memory, of course. From then on, however, the database is locked by the original Apache process. No script can make another reserved lock on the database until Apache is restarted.

Shouldn't PHP close the database connection when the script is terminated? Is this a bug in PHP? Would it be solved by running it as a FastCGI process?

Comment: How could that script ever finish? you're running a `while(true)` loop, which by definition is an infinite loop. it'll keep running until the server is restarted or the script exceeds php's `max_execution_time`. PHP does clean after itself, but for external stuff like DB's it's dependented on that particular plugin to do its own cleanup as well.

Comment: @MarcB I think that's the point OP is trying to illustrate. OP, I don't think you're going to get much of an answer here regarding whether or not this is a *bug* (SO is not a PHP bug tracker). As for your FastCGI question, try it and see.

Comment: @Phil I will try and see. Never submitted a bug before, so hopefully they don't firebomb my house.

Comment: @DylanSharhon Generally they will just flat-out ignore bug reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, SQLite uses a POSIX advisory lock on the database file.

The operating system will clean up this lock when the process exits.
However, as long as the Apache process that has an active transaction is still running, this lock remains.

If you have misbehaving scripts, you should run them in a way where aborting them kills the entire process.

Comment: How would you do that here? Start a new PHP CGI with each request? Not that the script should ever crash while using SQLite3Stmt, I just discovered the problem when I made a syntax error in development.

Comment: At least for the offending script.